# Is content within ember #each google crawl-able?

Tags: ember.js, web-crawler

I am quite new on ember and currently evaluating it. I know there are similar questions asked here, and I have read about google's document about html snapshots, the majority is about resolving user interactions but I don't seem to be able to find an answer about initial content being rendered within ember loops.

For example:

```
{{#each links}}
   <li><a href="{{url}}">{{label}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

So, without properly executing the javascript, google won't be able to index the links generated by ember. I have heard that google executes javascript, to a degree, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde where should I ask this question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will not index content that Ember renders in templates. You have to provide the data in some other way.

Robin Ward has a great post on the approach used by Discourse here: http://eviltrout.com/2013/06/19/adding-support-for-search-engines-to-your-javascript-applications.html

In summary, they use the HTML 5 History API and render basic markup for search engines into a `<noscript>` tag.